# on hover/mouseover change color AND scale?

Tags: jquery, effects

I'm trying to create buttons that are small, and grey until moused over- then they become large and colored.

I've used Soh Tanaka's awesome greyscale tutorial- 
but I can't figure out how to add the additional parameter of having the images also get bigger when moused over.

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/hover-over-trick/

any help is appreciated!!

Comment: You can animate their `width` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Just animate width, height, top, left and margins. Here's a snippet from http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/fancy-thumbnail-hover-effect-w-jquery/

```
 $("ul.thumb li").hover(function() {
        $(this).css({'z-index' : '10'}); /*Add a higher z-index value so this image stays on top*/ 
        $(this).find('img').addClass("hover").stop() /* Add class of "hover", then stop animation queue buildup*/
            .animate({
                marginTop: '-110px', /* The next 4 lines will vertically align this image */ 
                marginLeft: '-110px',
                top: '50%',
                left: '50%',
                width: '174px', /* Set new width */
                height: '174px', /* Set new height */
                padding: '20px'
            }, 200); /* this value of "200" is the speed of how fast/slow this hover animates */

        } , function() {
        $(this).css({'z-index' : '0'}); /* Set z-index back to 0 */
        $(this).find('img').removeClass("hover").stop()  /* Remove the "hover" class , then stop animation queue buildup*/
            .animate({
                marginTop: '0', /* Set alignment back to default */
                marginLeft: '0',
                top: '0',
                left: '0',
                width: '100px', /* Set width back to default */
                height: '100px', /* Set height back to default */
                padding: '5px'
            }, 400);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this one make Two class 
    .before_hover{
         width:10px;
         height:10px;
     }
    .on_hover{
         width:10px !important;
         height:10px !important;
     } 

  Jquery 
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('ul li').hover(function(){
       $(this).siblings().removeClass('on_hover'); 
       $(this).addClass('on_hover');
      },
      function(){
      });

   });

    you can make required changes in css.
```